# mlbench synthetic datasets for python

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset

Is there any implementation of the [synthetic datasets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW3hH.png) from [mlbench](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlbench/index.html) in python?
I am looking for [these](https://github.com/cran/mlbench/blob/fb911b680c2de78964da7b93be7d481ff8464627/R/mlbench-class.R) implementations in particular.
I've found [sklearn.datasets](https://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.datasets) for synthetic examples, but they do not contain the sets from mlbench.